# DSA Graphs: How do I programmatically partition n points into N groups so that intuitively within each group the points are 'close' together?

Tags: c++, algorithm, structure, cluster-analysis

As the title suggests, I want help with developing an algorithm that efficiently partitions a number(n) of points together into a number(N) of groups, based on how close the items are. In the end, I want to display the groups that were formed with the smallest error possible.

The points in question

[image]

More precisely, each point is a number on the x-axis, and the measurement of how 'good' a partitioning is can be defined as this formula: All the points summed divided by the number of total points.

I tried making a function that calculates the error between the given points, and I can do that just fine, but I am facing some difficulty with displaying the groups.

Comment: This is called a clustering problem.  There are lots of clustering algorithms to choose from.  You will have to experiment to find that suits your needs best.  I recommend starting with the the K-means algorithm - it is simple and often quite sufficient.

Comment: Another place to start, is an application that finds the clusters along a line to optimize placing servers amongst clients.  https://github.com/JamesBremner/Servitor

Comment: *As the title suggests* -- What is a "DSA Graph"?

Answer (score 1):

If all the points are on the x axis then there is 1 way which seems relatively obvious and fast.
Calculate the difference between adjacent points (might need a sort to get this sequence) and then partition along the k largest differences to get k + 1 clusters. complexity would be nlog(n) and it would optimize for clusters using minimum space on the x axis.